# How to move HTML tag inside JavaScript correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

I want move HTML tag inside JavaScript

My HTML Code is:

```
<tr>
...

    <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('{{ url('hotel/cancel-policy?NationCd='.$hotel_request['NationCd'].'&CityCd='.$hotel_request['CityCd'].'&CheckIn='.$hotel_request['CheckIn'].'&CheckOut='.$hotel_request['CheckOut'].'&Sgl='.$hotel_request['Sgl'].'&Dbl='.$hotel_request['Dbl']) }}', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">Cancel Policy</a></td>    
...

</tr>
```

My JavaScript Code is:

```
...
    elem.append('<tr>\
...
        <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('url('hotel/cancel-policy?NationCd='+NationCd+'&CityCd='+CityCd+'&CheckIn='+CheckIn+'&CheckOut='+CheckOut+'&Sgl='+Sgl+'&Dbl='+Dbl)', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">Cancel Policy</a></td>\
...
    </tr>');
...
```

But, it's not working

Comment: How you initialize elem?

Comment: @geckob, `var elem = $parent.find('.loading').empty();`.  How to move html tag(link href) inside javascript? It looks like it's just a matter of writing quotes. But I am confused

Comment: This wont work in plain js because append is expecting to receive the node object instead of a plain string. Using jQuery will works as it will convert the string to DOM element and append it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to run this code, the key is to use double quotes to wrap this character~

```js
$('#test').click(
  function() {
    $('#add').append('<tr><td><a href="#"' + 'onclick=' + "url('onclick=window.open('{{ url('hotel/cancel-policy?NationCd='.$hotel_request['NationCd'].'&CityCd='.$hotel_request['CityCd'].'&CheckIn='.$hotel_request['CheckIn'].'&CheckOut='.$hotel_request['CheckOut'].'&Sgl='.$hotel_request['Sgl'].'&Dbl='.$hotel_request['Dbl']) }}', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;" + ')' + '>Cancel Policy</a></td></tr>');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add"></div>
<tr id="td">
  <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('{{ url('hotel/cancel-policy?NationCd='.$hotel_request['NationCd'].'&CityCd='.$hotel_request['CityCd'].'&CheckIn='.$hotel_request['CheckIn'].'&CheckOut='.$hotel_request['CheckOut'].'&Sgl='.$hotel_request['Sgl'].'&Dbl='.$hotel_request['Dbl']) }}', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">Cancel Policy</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<button id="test">test</button>
```

See More Tutorials:https://github.com/AutumnsWind

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269200/how-to-display-json-object-to-html?noredirect=1#comment62064748_37269200

Answer (score 1):

**1. Using innerHTML**

Using innerHTML is working but it is actually overwriting all child elements of the element you are targeting. If the element is empty, it works perfectly fine I believe. So, as Amitesh Kumar answer:

```
var node = document.getElementById('node-id');
node.innerHTML = '<p>some dynamic html</p>';
```

**2. Using appendChild**

Another way is actually using the `appendChild` method but you need to convert the plain text to DOM nodes first. One way to do it is by creating an element and set the innerHTML using the plain string. Then, use the childNodes[0] property which is now a DOM element to append it to your targeted DOM object.

```
var el = document.getElementbyId('container')
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<p> This is the test element </p>';
el.appendChild(div.childNodes[0]);
```

**3. Using jQuery**

jQuery has `append` function which I believe should work in your case.

```
$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Refer: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Why are you writing `innerHTML` as a function? That's gonna do nothing but throw errors.

Comment: @JimboJonny: Which part?

Comment: @JimboJonny: I get your mean. It was as mentioned Amitesh answer. So I copied paste just now without putting much attention to it. Now I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
HTML into `<div id="node-id"></div>`



 Using innerHTML on a node:

    var node = document.getElementById('node-id');
    node.innerHTML= '<p>some dynamic html</p>';
```

Comment: I find it difficult to implement it into my case. My case seems only to the writing quotes

Comment: you are making it so hard first try with simple examples , then go for hard one, i think you are newbie.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar - he might also be having a hard time with your example because `innerHTML` is supposed to be a property, not a method. `node.innerHTML = '<p>content</p>';`, **not** `node.innerHTML('<p>content</p>');`