# How to display json object to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

My Json Object is like this :

```
[{
    "attributes": {
        "Code": "SGL",
        "Total": "19421340.27"
    },
    "DayPrice": [{
        "Date": "2016-07-22",
        "Rate": "4900439.85"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-23",
        "Rate": "4845150.21"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-24",
        "Rate": "4845150.21"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-25",
        "Rate": "4830600"
    }]
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "Code": "DBL",
        "Total": "6473780.09"
    },
    "DayPrice": [{
        "Date": "2016-07-22",
        "Rate": "1633479.95"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-23",
        "Rate": "1615050.07"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-24",
        "Rate": "1615050.07"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-25",
        "Rate": "1610200"
    }]
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "Code": "QUAD",
        "Total": "6473780.09"
    },
    "DayPrice": [{
        "Date": "2016-07-22",
        "Rate": "1633479.95"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-23",
        "Rate": "1615050.07"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-24",
        "Rate": "1615050.07"
    }, {
        "Date": "2016-07-25",
        "Rate": "1610200"
    }]
}]
```

From the json object array, I want display like this image:

[image]

I had try it, but I'm still confused. 
I feel it can not be done.

I try loop in loop like this :

```
countRoomType = json_object.length;
for(var i=0; i<countRoomType; i++){ 
    countDayPrice = json_object[i].DayPrice.length;
    for(var j=0; j<countDayPrice; j++){
        ...
    }
}
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: try jquery template plugin

Comment: @DharaParmar, See my question. I update it

Comment: I try loop in loop, but I'm still confused. It seems wrong

Comment: https://github.com/mastermatt/tmpljs

Comment: @MuhammedShevilKP, I want to change my json as the picture

Comment: is it ok if json get modified?

Comment: @Krupesh Kotecha, Json can not be modified. Json like that. If it can not be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` loop to iterate through the object.

**UPDATE**

Check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/7vcLxzyd/)

```
// Create a new blank object
var dateObj = {};

// Iterate original object
for (key in json_object) {
  var obj = json_object[key];
  var day = obj.DayPrice;
  for (dt in day) {
    var dtObj = day[dt];
    var dtKey = dtObj.Date;    
    if (dateObj.hasOwnProperty(dtKey)) {
        dateObj[dtKey].push({ Code: obj.attributes.Code, Rate: dtObj.Rate });
    } else {
        dateObj[dtKey] = [{ Code: obj.attributes.Code, Rate: dtObj.Rate }];
    }
  }
}

// Iterate the newly created object
for(d in dateObj) {
    var obj = dateObj[d];
    var row = '<tr><td>' + d + '</td><td><ul>';
  $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    console.log(val);
    row += '<li>' + val.Code + ': ' + val.Rate + '</li>';
  });
  row += '</ul></td></tr>';
  $('#target').find('tbody').append(row);
}
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this using **[`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)**

```js
var json_object = [{
  "attributes": {
    "Code": "SGL",
    "Total": "19421340.27"
  },
  "DayPrice": [{
    "Date": "2016-07-22",
    "Rate": "4900439.85"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-23",
    "Rate": "4845150.21"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-24",
    "Rate": "4845150.21"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-25",
    "Rate": "4830600"
  }]
}, {
  "attributes": {
    "Code": "DBL",
    "Total": "6473780.09"
  },
  "DayPrice": [{
    "Date": "2016-07-22",
    "Rate": "1633479.95"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-23",
    "Rate": "1615050.07"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-24",
    "Rate": "1615050.07"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-25",
    "Rate": "1610200"
  }]
}, {
  "attributes": {
    "Code": "QUAD",
    "Total": "6473780.09"
  },
  "DayPrice": [{
    "Date": "2016-07-22",
    "Rate": "1633479.95"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-23",
    "Rate": "1615050.07"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-24",
    "Rate": "1615050.07"
  }, {
    "Date": "2016-07-25",
    "Rate": "1610200"
  }]
}];

// generate the object for generating table easly 
var res = {};
json_object.forEach(function(v, i) {
  var code = v.attributes.Code; // get value of property code
  v.DayPrice.forEach(function(v1) {
    var date = v1.Date; // get date value from inner object
    res[date] = res[date] || {}; // initialize object with date if not 
    res[date][code] = v1.Rate; // add code value

  });
});

// genarate tr and td using generated object
$('#table').html($.map(res, function(v, i) { // iterate over the generated object
  return $('<tr/>', { // generate tr
    html: [$('<td/>', { // generate first column
      text: i // set first column value as date (key)
    }), $('<td/>', { // generate second column
      html: $.map(v, function(i1, v1) { // iterate over inner ibject to generate  second columnn  content
          return i1 + ':' + v1 + '(per room)'; // generate second column content
        }).join('<br>') // seperate each line using br tag
    })]
  })
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border=1></table>
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870

Comment: @samueltoh : check the comments added in your question

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** My understanding is that you want to rebuild your JSON, to do so you could follow some of the explenations below.

You could iterate through the whole JSON with forEach() method.
Something like this:

```
 json_object.forEach(function(v,i){
      v.DayPrice.forEach(function(vv,ii){
          var date = vv.Date;
          var rate = vv.Rate;
          var code = v.attributes.Code;
          var Total = v.attributes.Total;
          //below you can implement your own logic to not duplicate dates
          console.log(date + " : " + code+" : " + rate);

    })})
```

You will need to implement aditional logic on how to prevent date duplication. One suggestion is to build your own object and then use it to display the data like such:

```
var myObj = {};

json_object.forEach(function(v,i){
          v.DayPrice.forEach(function(vv,ii){
              var date = vv.Date;
              var rate = vv.Rate;
              var code = v.attributes.Code;
              var Total = v.attributes.Total;

              if(date in myObj){
               myObj[date].push({'code':code, 'rate':rate});                   
              }else{
               myObj[date] = [];
              }

        })})
```

Afterwards you need to Use the newly created myObj to append the values to the html either using lists or tables, its entirely up to you.
You can use this code:

```
for(key in myObj){
 //append the key asd value in the desired html element.
 myObj[key].forEach(function(v,i){
 var code = v.code;
 var rate = v.rate;
 //append code and rate to the corresponding html element
});

}
```

Comment: If you would like to implement it further please provide a sample html or even better a JSFiddle